# How to fix this issue about connecting to xrdp ? (parrotOS xfce on wsl2)

Tags: xfce, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xrdp

xypher@Oyo-chan:~$ `sudo systemctl enable xrdp`

[sudo] password for xypher:

```bash
Synchronizing state of xrdp.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable xrdp

Use of uninitialized value $service in hash element at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 26, <DATA> line 44.

Use of uninitialized value $service in hash element at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 26, <DATA> line 44.
```

Comment: What happens if you use the actual init style command, `sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start` instead of the systemd wrapper?